# Why current activity is closed when a nfc tag is recognized?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nfc

Why, when intent is thrown to recognize an NFC tag within a secondary activity, does this current activity automatically closes and returns arbitrarily main activity?

I'm working on an application in which the main activity (`MainActivity`) launches a new activity (`RegisterActivity`), in which I need to send a record to a cloud backend (`parse.com`) and then write on a label nfc code this new record. When I approached the NFC tag to the device, to write the code in it, the current activity (`RegisterActivity`) immediately closes and the main activity (`MainActivity`) opens, so it is not possible to write to the NFC tag.

Anyone know how to fix this? Here is the code of the two activities, as well as the manifest.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.prototiponfc.activities;

import com.example.prototiponfc.R;
import com.example.prototiponfc.R.id;
import com.example.prototiponfc.R.layout;
import com.example.prototiponfc.R.menu;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{

    //ImageView
    ImageView imgHeader;
    //Botones
    Button btnBuscar, btnRegistrar, btnTerminar;

    //Intent
    Intent intentBuscar, intentRegistrar;

    //Adaptador de nfc
    //NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgHeader = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewTitle);

        btnBuscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBusqueda);
        btnRegistrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNuevoRegistro);
        btnTerminar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTerminar);

        btnBuscar.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTerminar.setOnClickListener(this);

        //iniciar adaptador de nfc, con un contexto (la actividad)
//      mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
//      verificarEstadoDeNFC(mNfcAdapter);
    }

    private void verificarEstadoDeNFC(NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mNfcAdapter2 != null && mNfcAdapter2.isEnabled())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC disponible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC no disponible, Active el servicio" +
                    " e intente nuevamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Terminar actividad
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // solo lanzar la actividad correspondiente o terminar
        if (v.getId() == btnBuscar.getId())
        {
            intentBuscar = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentBuscar);
        }
        else if (v.getId() == btnRegistrar.getId())
        {
            intentRegistrar = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentRegistrar);
        }
        else if (v.getId() == btnTerminar.getId())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "¡Hasta luego!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Terminar
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

RegisterActivity

```
package com.example.prototiponfc.activities;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.nfc.FormatException;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.prototiponfc.R;
import com.example.prototiponfc.model.Persona;
import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

public class RegisterActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{

    /* codigo necesario para  distinguir cuando se obtenga la fotografia */
    private static final int LOAD_IMAGE=1;

    Button btnSelecFoto, btnRegresarAInicio, btnRegistrarUsuario;
    ImageView imageElement;
    EditText editNombre, editApellido, editCargo;

    private boolean hayImagen = false;

    private Intent intentNFC;

    private Parcelable nfcTag;

    private Bitmap myBitmap;

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        btnSelecFoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelecFoto);
        btnRegresarAInicio = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegresarAInicio);
        btnRegistrarUsuario = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrarUsuario);

        editNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNombre);
        editApellido = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editApellido);
        editCargo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCargo);

        btnSelecFoto.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRegresarAInicio.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRegistrarUsuario.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Conectar con backend de parse llave de app y de cliente
        Parse.initialize(getApplicationContext(), 
                "0nCpqh1JNL4zpVDePY9bqW60qwsc5ro5vADHuzzD",
                "phifCGjvsbxWHSzgbdCDiuIRtJeGk6fbQHD7kupD");

        //iniciar requestQueue
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        //mNfcAdapter = MainActivity.
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        //verificarEstadoDeNFC(mNfcAdapter);

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

            //Reconocer  la etiqueta            
        nfcTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        //Toast.makeText(this, ta.getTechList()[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        intentNFC = intent;
        disableForegroundDispatchSystem();
//      if (intentNFC.hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG))
//      {
//          Toast.makeText(this, "Etiqueta NFC detectada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//
//          Parcelable[] parcelables =intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
//          if (parcelables != null && parcelables.length > 0)
//          {
//              String mensajeNDEF = readTextFromNdefMessage((NdefMessage)parcelables[0]);
//
//              Toast.makeText(this, mensajeNDEF, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//          }
//          else
//          {
//              Toast.makeText(this, "No se encontraron mensajes ndef", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//          }   
//
//      }
    }
    //Leer desde la etiqueta nfc

    private String readTextFromNdefMessage(NdefMessage ndefMessage) {
        NdefRecord[] ndefRecords= ndefMessage.getRecords();

        if (ndefRecords != null && ndefRecords.length > 0)
        {
            NdefRecord ndefRecord = ndefRecords[0];
            String tagContent = getTextFromNdefRecord(ndefRecord);
            //Asignar el contenido de la etiqueta en el textview destinado para eso
            //txtNfcContenido.setText(tagContent);
            return tagContent;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No se encontraron records ndef", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }
    }
    public String getTextFromNdefRecord (NdefRecord ndefRecord)
    {
        String tagContent = null;
        try {
            byte[] payload = ndefRecord.getPayload();
            String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16" ;
            int languageSize = payload [0] & 0063 ;
            tagContent = new String(payload, languageSize + 1, 
                    payload.length - languageSize - 1, textEncoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("getTextFromNdefRecord", e.getMessage());
        }
        return tagContent;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.register, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onPause()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        disableForegroundDispatchSystem();      
    }

    private void disableForegroundDispatchSystem()
    {
        mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    /* de NFC ACTIVAR y desactivar lectura de tajertas */
    private void enableForegroundDispatchSystem()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING);

        PendingIntent mpPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        IntentFilter[] intentFilters = new IntentFilter[]{};

        mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mpPendingIntent, intentFilters, null);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onResume()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        enableForegroundDispatchSystem();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // las opciones son cargarFoto, registrar usuario o volver al inicio
        Toast.makeText(this, "Recuerde acercar la etiqueta NFC al\n" +
                " dispositivo para evitar errores", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        if (v.getId() == btnSelecFoto.getId())
        {
            cargarFotoDeGaleria();
        }
        else if (v.getId() == btnRegistrarUsuario.getId())
        {
            if (hayImagen == true) //si cargó imagen
            {
                if (editApellido.getText().length() > 0  && 
                        editNombre.getText().length() > 0 &&
                        editCargo.getText().length() > 0) //Si completó la informacionm
                {
                    String nombre = editNombre.getText()+"";
                    String apellido = editApellido.getText()+"";
                    String cargo = editCargo.getText()+"";
                    //                  if (nfcTag !=null) //Hay una etiqueta nfc disponible para escribir el código de registro en parse.com
                    //                  {
                    //                  registrarUsuario(nombre, apellido, cargo, myBitmap);
                    //                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Acerque la etiqueta NFC para guardar" +
                    //                          " el código asignado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                    if (nfcTag !=null && intentNFC != null) //si la acercó, se puede escribir
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Acerque la etiqueta NFC para guardar" +
                                " el código asignado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        registrarUsuario(nombre, apellido, cargo, myBitmap);

                        Persona ultimoElementoInsertado = obtenerUltimoRegistroDeParse();
                        if(ultimoElementoInsertado!=null)
                        {
                            //Reconocer  la etiqueta            
                            final Tag tag = intentNFC.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                            //Crear el mensaje para escribir en la etiqueta
                            Log.e("idInsertado", ultimoElementoInsertado.getId());
                            NdefMessage mnNdefMessage = createNdefMessage(ultimoElementoInsertado.getId());
                            //EScribir el mensaje en la etiqueta
                            writeNdefMessage(tag, mnNdefMessage);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PROBLEMAS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Debe acercar una etiqueta NFC para guardar" +
                                " información del usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Debe llenar todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No puede registrar un usuario si no selecciona una imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else if (v.getId() == btnRegresarAInicio.getId())
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            //Terminar ESTA actividad
            this.finish();
        }
    }

    private NdefRecord createTextRecord(String contenido)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] language;
            language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().getBytes("UTF-8");
            final byte[] text = contenido.getBytes("UTF-8");
            final int languageSize =language.length;
            final int textLength = text.length;
            final ByteArrayOutputStream payload = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1 + languageSize + textLength);

            payload.write((byte) ( languageSize & 0x1F));
            //El cero es el desplazamiento
            payload.write(language, 0, languageSize);
            payload.write(text, 0, textLength);

            return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], payload.toByteArray());
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ue)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR en createTextRecord", ue.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    private NdefMessage createNdefMessage(String content)
    {
        NdefRecord ndefRecord = createTextRecord(content);
        NdefMessage ndefMessage = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[]{ndefRecord});

        return ndefMessage;
    }

    private void writeNdefMessage(Tag tag, NdefMessage ndefMessage)
    {
        Log.e("mensaje ndef", ndefMessage.toString());
        try
        {
            if (tag == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Problemas al escribir en etiqueta \n" +
                        "(etiqueta no disponible o no reconocida)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);

            if (ndef == null) //si la tarjeta no tiene mensaje escrito(ndef)
            {
                //formatear la etiqueta con el formato ndef y escribir el mensaje
                formatNfcTag(tag, ndefMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                ndef.connect();
                if (!ndef.isWritable())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No es posible escribir en la etiqueta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //si no se puede escribir, se cierra y se detiene
                    ndef.close();
                    return;
                }
                Toast.makeText(this, "Se pudo escribir en la etiqueta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ndef.writeNdefMessage(ndefMessage);
                ndef.close();
            }

        }   
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR en write", io.getMessage() +"error");
        }
        catch(FormatException fe)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR en write", fe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void formatNfcTag(Tag tag, NdefMessage ndefMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            NdefFormatable ndefFormatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag);

            if (ndefFormatable == null) //la etiqueta no está enumerada en Tag.getTechList
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "La etiqueta no está disponible" +
                        " para formatear ()NdefFormteable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return; //para parar la aplicacion
            }
            ndefFormatable.connect();
            ndefFormatable.format(ndefMessage);
            ndefFormatable.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Se pudo escribir en la etiqueta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR", "eRROr de entrada salida (en formatNfcTag)");

        }
        catch(FormatException fe)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR", "eRROr al formatear etiqueta (en formatNfcTag)");
        }
    }

    private void escribirEnEtiqueta(String id) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nombre persona  :" + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    private Persona obtenerUltimoRegistroDeParse() {
        //obtener la tabla
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Persona"); //Todos
        final Persona persona = new Persona();
        //ParseObject obj = query.get("MaIMQ7Y0V4");
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt"); //de mayor a menor
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() { //El primero de los mayores, o sea, el último

            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject obj, ParseException arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String nombre = obj.getString("Nombre_persona");
                String apellido = obj.getString("Apellido_Persona");
                String id = obj.getObjectId();

                Log.e("PUTO ID", id.toString());
                String cargo = obj.getString("Cargo");
                ParseFile foto = obj.getParseFile("Foto_persona");
                Log.e("DE IMAGEN", foto.getUrl().toString());

                persona.setNombre(nombre);
                //              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cargo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                persona.setApellido(apellido);
                persona.setFotoUrl(foto.getUrl());
                persona.setCargo(cargo);
                persona.setId(id);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), persona.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), persona.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return persona;
    }

    private void registrarUsuario(String nombre, String apellido, String cargo, Bitmap myBitmap2) {
        //ParseObject imagenParseObject = new pa 
        ParseObject nuevoRegistro = new ParseObject("Persona");/*new ParseObject("PRUEBA");*/

        nuevoRegistro.put("Nombre_persona", nombre);
        nuevoRegistro.put("Apellido_Persona", apellido);
        nuevoRegistro.put("Cargo", cargo);
        //      nuevoRegistro.put("Foto_persona", myBitmap2);



        //Intentar guardar imagen
        // Save image file
        //      Drawable drawable = ...;
        //      Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myBitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();    
        //Ponerle nombre de la persona a la imagen
        String nombreImagen = nombre + "--image.jpg" ;
        ParseFile imageFile = new ParseFile(nombreImagen, data);
        //      imageFile.saveInBackground();
        nuevoRegistro.put("Foto_persona", imageFile);

        //ojo este si es el de guardar een parse
        nuevoRegistro.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseException arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registro exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("exito", "escritura en parse");
                limpiarPantalla();
            }


        }) ;
        //      //Tratar de recuperar de una vez el objectId
        //      ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Persona");
        //      ParseObject otro = query.get        
    }

    private void limpiarPantalla() {
        editApellido.setText("");
        editNombre.setText("");
        editCargo.setText("");
        imageElement.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    }

    private void cargarFotoDeGaleria() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Este es el intent que manejará la seleccion de imagen de la galeria
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        int code = LOAD_IMAGE;

        startActivityForResult(intent, code); // ---> Llama a onActivityResult
    }

    /*Recibe un código de petición (arg0), un código de respuesta (arg1)y datos(arg2)
     este maldito método sobreescrito de Activity, no de la puta ActionBarActivity es
     el que implementará que se cargue la puta imagen seleccionada, dentro del ImagwVIew*/
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //Para demoCamara verificar el codigo de peticion de la foto para saber como actuar qca en on activityResult
        switch (requestCode)
        {
        case LOAD_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                fromGallery(data);
            }
            break;
            //
            //      case CAMERA:
            //          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            //          {
            //              fromCamera(/*data*/);
            //          }
            //          break;
        }

    }

    public void fromGallery(Intent data)
    {
        if ( data != null) //cambiado para demoCamara,      
            //basada en la constante de esta clase y el codigo de respuesta fué una selección exitosa y hay datos
        {
            /* Declaro la uri de la imagen */
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData(); //datos tomados del intent quye se recibió

            /* Definir un cursor que será el que ejecute una consulta 
             * que finlmente mostrará la imagen, para crearlo se envia 
             * un arreglo de Strings que es el que lleva la columna seleccionada */
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            /*Ahora si el cursor: Uri corresponde a la imagen seleccionada, que
             * en este caso corresponde al Uri que se definió previamente, se envia el
             * filePathColumn como elemento de la proyección, como se quiere todo o recibido, 
             * entonces la seleccion será null y los argumentos de selección y ordenamiento
             * también serán null. NOTA::: Este tipo de seleccion de imagenes tambien es aplicable
             * para obtener otro tipo de archivos como canciones, videos, etc
             */
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

            //Asumon que si se seleccionó una imagen, por lo tanto:
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                //si hay al menos un primer resultado, entonces se obtiene la primera columna
                //obtengo el indice de la columna, correspondiente a la primera posicion del arreglo
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]); 
                //ahora obtener la ruta como un String      
                String picturePath=cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                //ahora se debe cerrar el cursor para liberar memoria
                cursor.close();
                //obtener el imageview para asignarle luego la imagen seleccionada
                //              ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
                imageElement = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageElement);
                //Se asigna la imagendecodificando el archivo en base a la ruta de la imagen, declarada unosd pasos antes
                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                //              imageElement.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                imageElement.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                hayImagen  = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.prototiponfc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!--
     To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
     option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies

    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <!-- To access Google+ APIs: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
                        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SearchActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.prototiponfc.activities.SearchResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_results" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

log when the nfc tag is recognized, before closing the current activity

```
09-03 21:34:58.456: V/WLAN_PSA(304): NL MSG, len[048], NL type[0x11] WNI type[0x5050] len[028]
09-03 21:34:59.096: D/dalvikvm(1578): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 75% free 2959K/11452K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 25ms
09-03 21:34:59.666: D/NfcAdaptation(1427): NfcAdaptation::HalDeviceContextDataCallback: len=4
09-03 21:34:59.666: I/BrcmNfcNfa(1427): NFC received ntf gid:0
09-03 21:34:59.666: I/BrcmNfcNfa(1427): nci_proc_core_ntf opcode:0x7
09-03 21:34:59.666: I/BrcmNfcNfa(1427): nfa_dm_nfc_response_cback () NFC_GEN_ERROR_REVT(0x500d)
09-03 21:34:59.666: I/BrcmNfcNfa(1427): nfa_dm_disc_data_cback ()
09-03 21:34:59.666: I/BrcmNfcNfa(1427): nfa_dm_disc_sm_execute (): state: DISCOVERY (1), event: INTF_ERROR_NTF(10) disc_flags: 0x1
09-03 21:34:59.666: I/Brcm (...)
```

Comment: Hello friend!This is de log when the nfc tag is recognized

Comment: See some working examples here: https://github.com/skjolber/ndef-tools-for-android

Answer (score -1):

When the logcat shows

> NFC received ntf gid:1

P2P of NFC will run well. When logcat shows

> NFC received ntf gid:0

it means the hardware may have something wrong. I had met this problem also, I change to another phone to test, it run well and from log ntp gid is 1.